# Tool that generate navigation from images

Tags: images, web, window, navigation

I have some of images and i want tool that allow me define a are on image that when click it navigate to another image and so on in all images ... i wish tool generate results as web pages

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you trying to generate an image map (like RedGrittyBrick [assumed](http://superuser.com/questions/224460/tool-that-generate-navigation-from-images/224464#224464))? Or [some photo gallery](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#example)?

Comment: i want to generate image map

Answer (score 1):

> Because creating image maps in a text editor requires much time and effort, there are many applications that allow the web designer to quickly and easily create image maps much as they would create shapes in a vector graphics editor. Examples of these are Adobe's Dreamweaver or KImageMapEditor (for KDE), and the imagemap plugin found in GIMP.

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)

Comment: I doubt the vague question is abut image maps, but the reference is good :-)